# How to assign two void* C

Tags: arrays, c, function, generics, void-pointers

I create in main.c an "hashmap" struct. it contains 6.000.000 "node" structs. i have to insert my elements by `insert` function. I didn't write it because it's not my trouble. If u need it I'll write it. Btw, the insert function is a generic function because data I need to insert every data type.In this case I insert a couple <key,value> of Integer. My trouble is : I have to make a function that return all key present in the hashmap t. In this function I have two parameters, both of them are `void*`. Key parameters in the hashmap are `void*`. The array that will contain all my keys, is `void*`. My aim is to put all my keys in this array and return it, but this is not possible ``` arr[j] = list->key; arr[j] = list->key;, the compiler gives me this error: *incomplite type of void* is not assignable*. Is there a way to resolve this thing?

**library.c**

```
struct node{
    void* key;
    void* val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct hashmap{
    int size;
    struct node **list;
};

void recoverkey(struct hashmap *t, void *arr){
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t->size; ++i) {
        struct node *list = t->list[i];
        while(list){
            if(list->key!=NULL) {
                arr[j] = list->key;
                j++;
            }
            list = list->next;
        }
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#define SIZEFILE 6000000

int main(){
    struct hashmap *t; // create hashmap
    insert(); // I insert elements in the hashmap

    int *arrRec;
    arrRec = malloc(SIZEFILE*sizeof(int));
    recoverkey(t,arrRec);
```

Comment: Perhaps you need a `void **`, so that the elements of the malloc'ed array are of type `void *`.

Comment: You are passing in an array of void * right to fill the list?  That is a pointer to a pointer needed for that - both in the `struct node` and in the function.  Also, your `recoverkey` function is trusting that arr is big enough a chunk of memory to receive the whole array,  That's a recipe for future issues in itself.

Comment: so I just need to create an array `void**` ? @MOehm

Comment: why do i need a pointer to a pointer in the `struct node`? @MichaelDorgan

Comment: Well, apparently your keys are generic pointers of type `void *`, so your array must be of type `*void[]` or, if you allocate dynamically, of type `void **`. As Michael notes, your `recoverkey` fuction should probably do the allocation, because it knows how much to allocate, whereas your client code in `main` must guess. [Here's](https://ideone.com/jo4ocg)  a cheap example.